# Where has this question gone?

Tags: discussion

Josh asked [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/396574/did-dickens-really-coin-never-say-never) about the etymology of the phrase 'Never say never'.  I found it interesting, upvoted and commented on it.  My inbox has a message someone sent me regarding it, but when I click on it, I get a 404 error.

What happened to it?

Comment: Most likely got deleted. Probably by Josh.

Comment: Josh usually deletes a post and undeletes it after making some important changes.

Comment: @NVZ thanks, I haven't been on this site for long enough!

Comment: @Josh aha.. looking forward to it!

Comment: We are waiting ...

Comment: @Josh again?! :D

Comment: [*And like that, he's gone*](https://pinkinkladies.files.wordpress.com/2015/05/bestgone.gif)

Comment: @Araucaria there's no rush...

Answer (score 7):

He deleted it. When you have 10K+ rep, you'll be able to view it again.

Comment: Quick question: Can moderators convert a question into an answer under another question?

Comment: No, we can only convert answers to comments.

Comment: thanks. Delete my comments.

Comment: What's the magic word?

Comment: Keyser Söze.. ;)

Comment: [Avada Kedavra](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avada-kedavra)